# MarkerWithLabel label center alignment

Tags: google-maps-api-3, alignment, center

I'm using the MarkerWithLabel extension in Google Maps API v3. I would like to set the label below the picture to be center aligned.
There is an LabelAnchor property that sets the position of the label, and I also use an CSS labelClass like this:

```
var myMarker = new MarkerWithLabel(
{
    position: latlng,
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "my text",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 0), //(25, 27),
    labelClass: "my_label", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.8},
    icon: image,
    labelInBackground: true,
    labelVisible: true,
    clickable: true,
    zIndex: 11
});

.my_label 
{
    color: black;
    background-color: beige;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;     
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius:3px;   
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888888;
}
```

Is it possible to auto align the label box, or do I need to calculate the text width and set the LabelAnchor manually? And if so, how do I calculate the text width?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not my solution, but there's a blog post at http://shahjahanrussell.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/make-label-text-in-center-for-google.html that worked for me.  Essentially:

```
.labels{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and

```
function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
          draggable: true,
          map: map,
          labelContent: "example",
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
        });

      }
```

Answer (score 17):

The other solutions will work, but they either require a fixed width, a hook into an event, or need you to wrap your content in a parent container and add a bunch of styling. Since the label is a DOM element that can take CSS styling, the easiest way to center the label is to simply use `transform: translateX(-50%)` in the CSS:

JS:

```
new MarkerWithLabel({
  labelAnchor: { x: 0, y: 30 },
  labelClass: 'marker-label'
})
```

CSS:

```
.marker-label {
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

You may have to bump the labelAnchor X a pixel or two to make it look visually centered.

Comment: easiest and fastest way. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the answer. Thx!

Comment: This solution also works for most other html elements that have an "absolute" position and need to be centered to their container. So simple, yet invaluable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I've found is to give the labels a class (in this case 'map-label') and then use this code to reposition the labels based on their width once the map has loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    $('.map-label').each(function() {
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + ($(this).width() / 2) + 'px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to calculate and set the LabelAnchor manually. It wasn't too bad... I just figured out the amount of left padding in my label and then the width of the average character in a long string and added half of that value.

This method likely gets inaccurate if the browser uses a different font than I expect. A better method for this may be to build a function that can determine the label width via javascript and half it from there. Perhaps create a temporary invisible label object somewhere in the DOM and use a jQuery function to pull the width.

Comment: Yes, that's about the way It's done now. An example of the DOM/jQuery technique would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
labelContent: "<span><?php echo $airport->name ?></span>",
```

And use this style:

```
.label-airport {
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.label-airport span {
    color: #333;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    height: 18px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #009be0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require setting the label width. When the map's `idle` event fires for the first time, reposition each label and make it visible. I'm using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to iterate the arrays.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Remove setAnchor as it resets margin-left.
    MarkerLabel_.prototype.setAnchor = function() {};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});
    var markers = [];
    var locations = [];
    // …

    // Reposition each label and update the initial styles.
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        _.each(markers, function(marker, idx) {
            var el = $(".map-label-" + idx);
            var width = el.width();
            var css = { "margin-left": -width / 2.0 + "px", opacity: 1 };
            marker.labelStyle = css;
            el.css(css);
        });
    });

    // Create markers with `labelClass` set to `map-label`.
    // Also set the initial opacity to zero in CSS.
    _.each(locations, function(location, idx) {
        var text = document.createTextNode(location.label);
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            map: map,
            // …
            labelClass: "map-label map-label-" + idx,
            labelStyle: { opacity: 0 }
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by wrapping the label content with `<span>`, which gets centered inside a wide, invisible, label div. This method requires you to define a maximum label width.

http://jsfiddle.net/TT26w/7/

```
div.label {
    display:block;
    width:500px; /* Maximum width of label */
    margin-left:-250px; /* 1/2 maximum width of label */
    margin-top:-30px; /* vertical offset, negative is up */
    text-align:center;
}

div.label span {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width:500px; /* Maximum width of label */
    min-width:50px; /* Minimum width of label */
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    color:white;
    background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could add your Javascript declaration of your `MarkerWithLabel` object?  I'm trying to use the method described but seem to be running into some issues.